# Changing colour over many loops of a function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a recursive fractal tree program in **Javascript**. The way it operates can be described as follows.

Imagine a turtle draws a line. From the end of that line, it rotates left, draws a line, then rotates right and draws a second line. This is repeated for the two new lines that were drawn, and so on until a beautiful fractal tree with many branches exists.

However, I want the tree to start brown and turn more green with each new branch, [like this one here](http://tinypic.com/r/e7molf/9). I can make every right sided branch red or every left sided branch yellow, but I want each branch that is created to be slightly less brown and more green than it's predecessor. I could achieve this with an integer variable like length, because the length of each new branch could be equal to `length - y` , making smaller branches each time.

How could I do this with a colour? It's not like I could do `stroke(brown - (a bit of brown)).

Anyway, to reinstate, I'd like a way in **Javascript** to make each branch generated less brown and more green than the last, much like how you can make each branch smaller than the last with `length = length - y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS allows you to express a color in the RGB format (Red, Green, Blue). E.g: The color white, most commonly coded in CSS as #ffffff can be coded as rgb(255, 255, 255).

In RGB, the higher the value of the second argument - which stands for green - the more greenish the produced color will be.

Start from brown, keep adding green and voila!

https://jsfiddle.net/r9gajrdd/5/

```
let red = 118;
let green = 89;
let blue = 3;
let rgb;

for ( let i = 10; i--; ) {
    green = Math.min(green + 10, 253);
    rgb = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple answer, just what I was looking for.